# Kotlin multiple inheritance between interfaces

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin, interface

i want to know if there'a way to declare that an interface extends another interface with three different generics type parameters

```
interface AggDBTree: DBTreeInterface<T, X, V>{
 //method declarations
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that superinterface to have three different generic parameters, you can do that:

```
interface DBTreeInterface<A, B, C>

interface AggDBTree<T, X, V> : DBTreeInterface<T, X, V>
```

If you want to implement the same interface, but with various type parameters, that is not possible. So something like this will *not* compile:

```
interface DBTreeInterface<T>

interface AggDBTree<A, B> : DBTreeInterface<A>, DBTreeInterface<B>
```

You can only extend a single interface once.